# Sound to electrical energy converter (Energy Harvesing)

Tags: converter

Is it possible harvest sound and convert it into a usable electrical energy

Ex. You want to charge your phone using sound energy

Comment: The challenges are already been explained in the responses to the question you asked only around 30 minutes before this one: "[Amplifying 10-30mV into atleast 5V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342713/amplifying-10-30mv-into-atleast-5v)". VTC as duplicate of that one.

Comment: ... asked by the same user 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @Transistor - Sorry, I was editing the "default" system-added comment (and ran out of time to correct my grammar mistakes [*sigh*]) and it turns out that I added the same points as you did! Great minds think alike and all that ;-) No plagiarism intended!

Comment: @Transistor I didn't notice. Added my close vote.

Comment: Why bother? Anything loud enough for that to work probably has a hefty alternator on it, probably 400Hz too.

Comment: I guess you could hook a couple of wires and a circuit into the back of the speaker and listen to heavy metal all night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, **no**.

The output power from typical microphones which generally directly convert sound to voltage and current output milivolts and miliamps at best. Phones charge on 5V 0.5 amps generally. So unless you're going to create an array of thousands or millions of microphones and have a reasonably loud room, this will never work.